# How to find all directories by keyword and create .htaccess file with the same content automatically?

Tags: linux, shell

I need to find all folders on a Linux server with directory name `config` and put a `.htaccess` in that directory containing "`deny from all`".

I'm currently trying to run:

```
find /home/www/sites/ -type d -name "config" -exec sh -c 'echo "deny from all" > .htaccess' \;
```

But it doesn't work.

What have I missed?

Comment: Define "doesn't work".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
find /home/www/sites/ -type d -name "config" -exec sh -c 'echo "deny from all" > {}/.htaccess' \;
```